# How to run Ranorex tests in a specific browser version?

Tags: ranorex

The [OpenBrowser method](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/M_Ranorex_Host_OpenBrowser_5.htm) seems to allow a browser-name only, but does not allow to specify a browser version.

Is there any official way, or do you know any good alternative (e.g. via custom code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ranorex support pointed out that the `OpenBrowser` method does not accept a specific browser version by design.

If you want to test on various browser versions, the suggested approach is to run the test suite on multiple virtual machines having different browser versions installed.